# How to add same value to multiple columns based on a particular column value?

Tags: r

I have a df with 4 columns

```
Col0  Col1  Col2  COl3  Col4
  1    0     NA    NA   NA
  2    0     NA    NA   NA
  3    1     NA    NA   NA
  3    0     NA    NA   NA
  5    1     NA    NA   NA
```

I need to fill Col2, Col3 and Col4 based on the values of Col1
So if Col1 is 0, Col2,Col3 and Col4 should be filled with 0
If Col1 is 1, Col2,Col3 and Col4 should be filled with the value of Col0
Else Col2,Col3 and Col4 should be filled with the value of average of Col0 and Col1.

`df$Col2[df$Col1==0]<-0` affects only 1 column.

Expected output:

```
Col0  Col1  Col2  COl3  Col4
  1    0     0    0   0
  2    0     0    0   0
  3    1     3    3   3
  3    0     0    0   0
  5    1     3    3   3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Col0<-c(1,2,3,3,5)
Col1<-c(0,0,1,0,1)
Col2<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
Col3<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
Col4<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

df<-data.frame(Col0,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4)


  df[which(df$Col1 == 0),3:5] <- 0
  df[which(df$Col1 == 1),3:5] <- df[which(df$Col1 == 1),1]
  df[which(df$Col1 != 1 & df$Col1 != 0),3:5] <- 
    mean(df[which(df$Col1 != 1 & df$Col1 != 0),1],df[which(df$Col1 != 1 & df$Col1 != 0),2])

#df:     
  Col0 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1    1    0    0    0    0
2    2    0    0    0    0
3    3    1    3    3    3
4    3    0    0    0    0
5    5    1    5    5    5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate the mean value for the rows beforehand using `rowMeans` and then use nested `ifelse` and replace values in columns.

```
mean_vals <- rowMeans(df[1:2])
df[3:5] <- with(df, ifelse(Col1 == 0, 0, ifelse(Col1 == 1, Col0, mean_vals)))

df
#  Col0 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#1    1    0    0    0    0
#2    2    0    0    0    0
#3    3    1    3    3    3
#4    3    0    0    0    0
#5    5    1    5    5    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want the rest of the columns to be a weighted average of `Col0` and `Col1` where possible weights are 0, 0.5, and 1. We can get the weights for `Col0` with

```
(idx <- ((df$Col1 != 0) + (df$Col1 == 1)) / 2)
# [1] 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.5
```

so that it's 0 if the corresponding element of `Col1` is 0; it's 1 if the corresponding element of `Col1` is 1; and it's 0.5 otherwise. Thus,

```
df[-1:-2] <- df$Col0 * idx + df$Col1 * (1 - idx)
df
#   Col0 Col1 Col2 COl3 Col4
# 1    1    0    0    0    0
# 2    2    0    0    0    0
# 3    3    1    3    3    3
# 4    3    0    0    0    0
# 5    5    1    5    5    5
```